# Pass argument in method called through SerializerMethodField

Tags: django-rest-framework, serialization

I defined a serializer using the following code:

```
class TermSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    associatedVocabs = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_assocVocabs')
    equivalentVocabs = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_equivVocabs')

    def get_assocVocabs(self,obj):
        vocabs = Vocab.objects.none()
        related = RelationTerm.objects.filter(from_term = obj.id, relation=1)
        return related

    def get_equivVocabs(self,obj):
        vocabs = Vocab.objects.none()
        related = RelationTerm.objects.filter(from_term = obj.id, relation=2)
        return related

    class Meta:
        model = Term
        fields = ('id', 'associatedVocabs', 'equivalentVocabs')
```

As you can see in this serializer I defined two methods:`get_assocVocabs` and `get_equivVocabs`. 
They are exactly the same, what changes is the value of relation in filter, 1 is to filter associated vocabs, and 2 is to get equivalent vocabs.

By the way, this is my viewset:

```
class TermViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = (TermJSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer, )
    serializer_class = TermSerializer
    allowed_methods = ('GET','OPTIONS','HEAD')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Term.objects.all()
        word = self.request.query_params.get('word', None)
        if word is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(word__iexact=word)
        return queryset
```

What I need is to avoid having two equal methods inside the serializer, when I can have just one (because they do the same) if I pass an argument to filter the relation field.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is there any relation between `RelationTerm.relation` and the `Term` object?

Comment: I just want to know how to pass an argument to the method 'get_assocVocabs' using SerializerMethodField. Why do you need to know that?

Comment: Rather new to django, I'm having the exact same use case. Did you ever find out?

Answer (score 2):

I'd add your obj to the [serializer's context](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) and fetch it from your method.